# jQuery String Manipulation

Tags: javascript, string

I am working on some string manipulation using jQuery.

Basically, within a .click(function(){ I have the following string variable:

```
f?p=251:1007:3642668879504810:::::
```

What I need to do using jQuery is basically remove the number 3642668879504810 (which changes, i.e is a random number so cannot match on this number) between the second and third colon within this string variable, so the end result would be as follows, still maintaining all the colons

```
f?p=251:1007::::::
```

Comment: This is a javascript question, not a jquery question.
You can use the .indexOf() and .substr() functions to get what you want.  Find the text from the 2nd colon to the end, then find the third colon and cut everything in between out.

Comment: Sorry - as I was performing my processing within a document.ready function, I thought it related to jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick way using `split()`:

```
var str, split_str, new_str;

str = 'f?p=251:1007:3642668879504810:::::';
split_str = str.split(':');
split_str[2] = '';
new_str = split_str.join(':');

// new_str == 'f?p=251:1007::::::'
```

Comment: Thanks Matchu but I was just wondering, I've noticed that sometimes before the f?p=251, there might be another value set, such as http://www.google.com/f?p=251:1007:3642668879504810:::::, based on this, is there a away to look for f?p= string and then start from here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
stringVar = stringVar.replace(/\d+(:+)$/, '$1');
```

Should work. It finds digits only followed by colons and replaces it with those colons (thereby removing the digits).

Comment: Took me a while to parse this one in my brain: removes the last number in the string before one or more colons.